# Can't set unslider delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unslider

It's all pretty standard actually. The code follows.
Everything works fine except the speed and delay. Delay just wouldn't change.

```
var unslider = $('.newbanner').unslider();
  $('.newbanner').unslider({
    speed : 100,               
    delay : 400000,
    dots : false,
     arrows : true,
    keys : true,

  });

 $('.unslider-arrow').click(function() {
    var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];
    unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
});
```

Comment: Try removing your initial declaration and just use the 2nd. Remove: `var unslider = $('.newbanner').unslider();` Change 2nd to: `var unslider = $('.newbanner').unslider({
    speed : 100,               
    delay : 400000,
    dots : false,
     arrows : true,
    keys : true,

  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try removing your initial declaration and just use the 2nd. Remove: var unslider = $('.newbanner').unslider(); Change 2nd to: var unslider = $('.newbanner').unslider({ speed : 100, delay : 400000, dots : false, arrows : true, keys : true, });

I read on their github that issues, with speed and delay, can arise if you instantiate the unslider then start it. This led me back to your script where I noticed you had 2 declarations.